# Mass Effect 2 bonuses

Tags: mass-effect-2

Does the outcome of the 1st playthrough of Mass Effect 2 matter? I mean Because I just want the bonuses for completing the game once specificly the extra 50,000 of each materials and 100,000 credits

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean does the choice you make at the end of the first play through affect the second one? If that's your question, then no it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

No. Only the decisions of the current play through will matter on the third game. So you can experiment on your first play through and then get the bonuses and plan your second play through.